# VBA Check if file (from website) exists

Tags: vba, excel

Please bear with me as I am a beginner at VBA.

I am trying to open an excel file through a website using VBA. The address (path) of the file changes from month to month. For example:

- In July, the file name is: http://www.clevelandfed.org/research/data/inflation_expectations/2014/July/excel1.xls
- In August, the file name is: http://www.clevelandfed.org/research/data/inflation_expectations/2014/August/excel1.xls

The problem is that I never know in advance when the new file for the month is going to be published. Therefore, I need to check in the VBA code if the current month file exist, if not, I would just open the previous month file.

This is what I have tried:

```
Dim DirFile As String
Dim wbA As Workbook

DirFile = "http://www.clevelandfed.org/research/data/inflation_expectations/" & Format(Now, "YYYY") & "/" & Format(Now, "MMMM") & "/excel1.xls"

' Check if the file for current month does not exist, open previous month's file
If Len(Dir(DirFile)) = 0 Then
    Set wbA = Workbooks.Open("http://www.clevelandfed.org/research/data/inflation_expectations/" & Format(Now, "YYYY") & "/" & Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "MMMM") & "/excel1.xls", IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)

'If the current month file exists, open it
Else
    Set wbA = Workbooks.Open(DirFile, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
End If
```

However, this results in an error:

[image]

I am assuming this is due to the fact that this is a file that resides on a website. Could anyone please help resolve this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct in assuming `Dir()` doesn't work for files residing on Websites

[Dir Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dir-function-HA001228824.aspx)
Returns a String representing the name of a file, directory, or folder that matches a specified pattern or file attribute, or the volume label of a drive.

What you need is the [following function to check if the URL is valid](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/567315-check-if-url-exists-so-then-return-true.html),
***P.S. Place the function in Module***

```
Function URLExists(url As String) As Boolean
    Dim Request As Object
    Dim ff As Integer
    Dim rc As Variant

    On Error GoTo EndNow
    Set Request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    With Request
      .Open "GET", url, False
      .Send
      rc = .StatusText
    End With
    Set Request = Nothing
    If rc = "OK" Then URLExists = True

    Exit Function
EndNow:
End Function
```

Then use the function in your Macro

```
If URLExists(DirFile) = 0 Then
    Set wbA = Workbooks.Open("http://www.clevelandfed.org/research/data/inflation_expectations/" & Format(Now, "YYYY") & "/" & Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "MMMM") & "/excel1.xls", IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
    wbA.Activate
'If the current month file exists, open it
Else
    Set wbA = Workbooks.Open(DirFile, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
End If
```

Comment: This is perfect!!! Thank you so much!! (P.S: I assume you have to put the function definition on a different module, right?) Thanks a lot again, it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

This solution works, even using late binding, so you do not need to add a library manually:

```
Public Function CheckUrlExists(url) As Boolean
        
    On Error GoTo CheckUrlExists_Error
    
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
 
    xmlhttp.Open "HEAD", url, False
    xmlhttp.send
    
    If xmlhttp.Status = 200 Then
        CheckUrlExists = True
    Else
        CheckUrlExists = False
    End If
    
    Exit Function
    
CheckUrlExists_Error:
    CheckUrlExists = False
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative. Just try to open it and see if it fails. If it does, open last months.  Not better, just different.

```
Public Function GetCFWorkbook() As Workbook

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim dt As Date

    dt = Now

    Const sURL As String = "http://www.clevelandfed.org/research/data/inflation_expectations/"

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sURL & Format(dt, "yyyy/mmmm") & "/excel1.xls")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    If wb Is Nothing Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sURL & Format(DateAdd("m", -1, dt), "yyyy/mmmm") & "/excel1.xls")
    End If

    Set GetCFWorkbook = wb

End Function
```