# How to test if a document exists in OneDrive before attempting to open

Tags: vba, onedrive

I'm writing some VBA in PowerPoint saved in Office 365 OneDrive which is opening an Excel workbook. This is the example code:

```
Sub TestOpen()
Dim FilePath As String
FilePath = "https://mytenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user_name_mytenant_com/Documents/Workbook.xlsx"
Dim ExcelApp As New Excel.Application
Dim ExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Set ExcelWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(FilePath, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
MsgBox "Workbook opened and contains " & ExcelWorkbook.Sheets.Count & " sheets", vbInformation
ExcelWorkbook.Close False
Set ExcelWorkbook = Nothing
ExcelApp.Quit
Set ExcelApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

This works fine.

However, if the file doesn't exist, the `ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open` call hangs. You can get control back by ending the spawned excel.exe task at which point an error is thrown.

I suspect there isn't much one can do to make the Open method return if the file exist - it's possible that there is a prompt being displayed that the user can't see.

Another way to tackle this would be to see if the document at least existed before trying the Open method. So another question is how do you test from VBA that a file exists in OneDrive? I'm thinking along the lines of a web request as this is done via HTTP but haven't a clue what request to fire off?

UPDATE:

I've just run similar code in Excel itself as that allows one to see any error message and it indeed does throw an untrappable error:

[image]

So yes, my question is how can you check a document exists in OneDrive before attempting to open it.

Comment: A fudge (spawning Office apps is always a fudge) is to add ExcelApp.Visible = True which brings the spawned Excel into view so the user can see the error. Not ideal but okay for now. Still like to know how to test if the document exists first

Comment: You might check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428611/vba-check-if-file-from-website-exists to see if that would work in your scenario...

Comment: @AdamsTips it does not work, using OneDrive a (default) file ist created/returned even if the file does not exist in OneDrive

Comment: Hmm, my experience with OneDrive is that it can cause more problems than it fixes..