# VBA code to know URL validity that will check whether URL is exist or not

Tags: excel, vba, url

I have code to know the URL existence but in many other systems or may another office version it is not working. could please help me with this? Where is im doing wrong? Is there an alternate option? Thanks in advance
I am using code to know URL VALIDITY is

```
Public Function IsURLGood(URL As String) As Boolean
Dim request As New WinHttpRequest

On Error GoTo IsURLGoodError
request.Open "HEAD", URL
request.send
If request.Status = 200 Then
    IsURLGood = True
Else
    IsURLGood = False
End If
Exit Function

IsURLGoodError:
IsURLGood = False
End Function
```

To check URL existence

```
If IsURLGood(Sheet1.Range("D10")) Then
'MsgBox "correct"
Else
MsgBox "URL is invalid."
    End If
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Application.WorksheetFunction.WebService` return an error if a URL is invalid? Catch that error to know if an URL is valid. No experience on it myself if this is 100% correct.

Comment: You might try [VBA Check if file (from website) exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25428811/11167163)

Comment: we need details. On what systems does it work and what signifies it is working? On what systems and versions doesn't it work and how does this not working manifest itself? Can you give us instructions to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I usually shared the workbook with others. in some office version, it is not working. it may be due to **WINHTTP** reference not selected as it is shared with other version or other office settings in VBA. I'm not sure what exactly issue is there. I got this error in 7 out of 10 with a different pc/office versions.