# I use a VBA function to extract a hyperlink in Excel, need to return either the Link, or "" if it's not a hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I use an excel spreadsheet with an embedded function to return hyperlinked cells.  When a cell isn't hyperlinked, the sheet returns " #VALUE!", and I'd like it to return a null ("").  How do I update the function to return the link, or return a ""...?

Here's the function, and it works great - I just want to add "if URL exists, return it, if not a URL, then "" :

```
Function URL(Hyperlink As Range)
   URL = Hyperlink.Hyperlinks(1).Address
End Function
```

Comment: Have you considered testing `If Hyperlink.Hyperlinks.Count > 0`?

Answer (score 1):

This code should give what the OP requested.

fnCheckHyperlink is the main calling function.

fnHasHyperlink returns `True` if the cell actually has a hyperlink in it.

fnURLExists uses the address in the hyperlink and checks that it exists.

fnHyperlinkAdd wraps the `.Hyperlink.Add` method of a Range and was useful in setting up the test data.

```
Option Explicit

Sub sbUsage()
 MsgBox fnCheckHyperlink(Range("A1"))
 MsgBox fnCheckHyperlink(Range("G1"))
End Sub

'"if URL exists, return it, if not a URL, then "" - Null
Public Function fnCheckHyperlink(rCell As Range) As String
    ' if URL exists ...
    ' 1. if cell has hyperlink
    ' 2. if URL exists
    ' so return it
 
 If fnHasHyperlink(rCell) Then
    If fnURLExists(rCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address) Then
        fnCheckHyperlink = rCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
    Else
        fnCheckHyperlink = ""
    End If
 Else
    fnCheckHyperlink = ""
 End If
End Function

Public Function fnURLExists(sURL As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo fnURLExists_Error
    Dim htRequest As New WinHttpRequest
    htRequest.Open "HEAD", sURL
    htRequest.Send
    If htRequest.Status = 200 Then
        fnURLExists = True
    Else
        fnURLExists = False
    End If
    Exit Function

fnURLExists_Error:
    'sbPrint ("fnURLExists_Error" & Err.Number & Err.Description)
    ' fnURLExists_Error -2147012890 The URL does not use a recognized protocol
    fnURLExists = False
End Function
Sub sbPrint(sText As String): Open "C:\tmp\z-" & Format(Now(), "HHMMSS") & ".txt" For Output As #1: Print #1, sText: Close #1: End Sub

Public Function fnHasHyperlink(rCell As Range) As Boolean
 If rCell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
    fnHasHyperlink = True
 Else
    fnHasHyperlink = False
 End If
 End Function

' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)#properties
' https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/what-is-the-proper-vba-syntax-to-check-if-a-cell-contains-a-hyperlink.849362/
' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78142219/i-use-a-vb-function-to-extract-a-hyperlink-in-excel-need-to-return-either-the-l
' https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/hyperlink-subaddress-fields-e46d7aa0-a71d-4289-a423-2a3e31c35f50
' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlinks.add
' expression.Add (Anchor, Address, SubAddress, ScreenTip, TextToDisplay)
' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770412/vba-function-optional-parameters
' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58117601/vba-code-to-know-url-validity-that-will-check-whether-url-is-exist-or-not

Public Function fnHyperlinkAdd(rnAnchor As Range, sAddress As String, Optional sSubAddress As String, Optional sScreenTip As String, Optional sTextToDisplay As String) As Boolean
 On Error GoTo fnHyperlinkAdd_Error
 With Sheets(1)
    .Hyperlinks.Add _
        Anchor:=rnAnchor, _
        Address:=sAddress, _
        SubAddress:=sSubAddress, _
        ScreenTip:=sScreenTip, _
        TextToDisplay:=sTextToDisplay
 End With
 fnHyperlinkAdd = True
 Exit Function

fnHyperlinkAdd_Error:
 fnHyperlinkAdd = False
End Function
```

[image: Test data and results]