# Check if file exists in OneDrive via VBA

Tags: vba, onedrive

I'm trying to check if an Excel file exists in OneDrive using `Dir(Filename)` (without opening it):

```
strFilePath = "https://d.docs.live.net/ce59asdf4hj34h5k/Folder 1/Folder 2/File.xlsm"
If Dir(strFilePath) <> "" Then
'do something
End If
```

but `Dir(Filename)` give me an error: `Run-time error '52': Bad filename or number`

I tried to do a workaround and check if the URL itself is valid [(using the code sample from here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25428811/2089396) unfortunately the URL is always valid regardless if the file exists or not (if the file in question does not exist One Drive seems to return a default file, at least that's what it does if you test it in a browser, see screenshot below)

[image]

Any other ideas on how to solve the problem would be appreciated (I'm trying to do this without actually opening the file since this will create other problems I'm trying to avoid).

Note: I have OneDrive (Sync) installed, but using a local path unfortunately is out of solution's scope. The Soultion has to work with files that are not synced locally.

Comment: `Dir` does not work for URL. Anyhow, URL uses slash, not backslash... You must check if URL is valid.

Comment: @FaneDuru the slashes were a typo, I corrected them, what exactly do you mean by "check if URL is valid"? Something else from what I tried?

Comment: I do not know what you tried... I will post an answer about how this can be accomplished...

Comment: @FaneDuru I tried the solution from the answer I linked to.

Comment: I didn't see that you edited your question... I used something similar. I do not see a reason to not returning the desired result. Did you try my answer code?

Comment: @FaneDuru I did, I used the same http-request. This does not work in OneDrive (see explanation in my question and my comment to your answer)