# Unexpecter error from UDF which checks if a file can be found

Tags: excel, vba

I have an if-statement in my code:

```
If sharepointFileExists(sFullFilePath) Or fileOnDisk(sFullFilePath) Then
```

which calls upon two functions:

```
Function fileOnDisk(ByVal strPath As String) As Boolean
    fileOnDisk = CBool(Len(Dir(strPath)) > 0)
End Function
```

and

```
Function sharepointFileExists(ByVal strUrl As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim oHttp As Object
    
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    oHttp.Open "HEAD", strUrl, False
    oHttp.Send
    'Debug.Print oHttp.Status
    sharepointFileExists = CBool(oHttp.Status = 200)
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    'Debug.Print Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    'Debug.Print "Feil: - " & oHttp.Status
    sharepointFileExists = False
End Function
```

I have several files which use this code, and in one of them I get an error even though the input should be similar for all of them.

In the function `fileOnDisk`, I get the error

> Run-time error '52': Bad file name or number

The argument supplied to the function is something like `https://nhy.sharepoint.com/teams/Team-xxxxxx/xxxx/xxxx/Excel-file.xlsx`, which I would expect `Dir` to not find on the disk and thus return a zero-length string ([as per the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function)). Instead I get the error described above.

Trying to print the argument to the immediate window when debugging the code gives the string value I'd expect.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what's going on here?

Comment: Do you really have to pass the same file to both functions? Can't you check if the Left() 4 characters is http and send the string to the appropriate function? Or in `fileOnDisk` check if it's http and just pass false back

Comment: Build error handling into `fileOnDisk`, similar to what you have already done in `sharepointFileExists`

Comment: @chrisneilsen Yeah, I'll probably just do that. Have you got any idea why this specific error occurs though? I can't really see why `Dir` doesn't want to handle this string, especially since it works fine in other versions of the file.

Comment: There are many strings that `Dir` can't interpret as paths, those beginning with `https://` are only a subset.

Comment: @eirikdaude Where do you see that Dir() should work on internet URL's?

Comment: @chrisneilsen Yeah. I tested with some other strings and it seems you are right. Do you know if this is documented anywhere? From microsoft's documentation I didn't get the impression that the input-string to the function was restricted in any way.

Comment: *Remarks
In Microsoft Windows, Dir supports the use of multiple character*  and then there is a chapter about Mac. But nothing about URL's

Comment: @eirikdaude I can find many non official references, but no official ones

Comment: If you could find something which looks reasonably trustworthy, and which covers the most common cases, I'll put a checkmark on your answer :-) I still find it weird that I don't get the error in other versions of the same file though - I guess I'll  have to check if I already added error-handling there ^_^ @chrisneilsen

Comment: https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/760481-retrieving-file-names-from-an-http-server-in-vba-dir-wont-work.html is one.

Comment: Perhaps even a possible duplicate close? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428611/vba-check-if-file-from-website-exists

Comment: I guess it depends on your use case, but I'd expect you'd want to return. `FALSE` for _any_ mal-formed parameter  passed to `fileOnDisk`, just like you do for `sharepointFileExists`.  By way of example, if you passed `X:\Y:\Z` I'd expect `FALSE` to be a reasonable response.

Comment: Ok, bad choice of example.  Try `X\:/Y` . My point was there are many possible invalid strings

Comment: @chrisneilsen Yeah, I suppose. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @eirikdaude the FileSystemObject answer provide a perfectly valid alternative, so I'm ok with you accepting that. I'd just like to say that AFAIK my answer produces _exactly_ the same result.  It's a shame the whole Q&A got sidetracked by Andreas' pedantry

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I tried not engaging, but you know :-/ Anyway, I see how both answers are valid solutions, and I've upvoted them both - unfortunately I can't accept two different ones, so I checkmarked Kostas'. Still curious about what valid syntax for pathnames in `Dir` are, my googling isn't turning much up, except similar questions. @chrisneilsen

Comment: @eirikdaude  no need to apologise, go with what works for you.  I think FilesystemObject and Dir will accept broadly the same paths.  Main difference seems to be if passed a syntacticly invalid path FilesystemObject handles it, Dir doesn't.  FYI,I'm going to clean up the distracting and unhelpfull comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Dir()` method throws an error if the parent directory does not exist. You need to use the `FileSystemObject` in this case which simply returns a boolean.

```
Function fileOnDisk(ByVal strPath As String) As Boolean
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        fileOnDisk = .FileExists(strPath)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: That seems to be more robust, at least. Thanks a lot for your help, I'll switch to this function in my code.

Comment: While Filesystemobject is a viable alternative,  your assertion the _The Dir() method throws an error if the parent directory does not exist_ is not correct.   It simply returns an empty string (provided the path passed is syntactic correct)

Answer (score 0):

Build error handling into `fileOnDisk`, similar to what you have already done in `sharepointFileExists`

There are many strings that Dir can't interpret as paths, those beginning with `https://` are only a subset

```vb
Function fileOnDisk(ByVal strPath As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo EH
    fileOnDisk = CBool(Len(Dir(strPath)) > 0)
Exit Function
EH:
    fileOnDisk = False
End Function
```

Answer (score -2):

Since dir() probably can't access files that is not local it gives an error message.
You could fix that by editing the fileOnDisk function like this:

```
Function fileOnDisk(ByVal strPath As String) As Boolean
    if left(lcase(strPath), 4) <> "http" then
        fileOnDisk = CBool(Len(Dir(strPath)) > 0)
    else
        fileOnDisk = false
    end if
End Function
```