# How do I check if the Selecteditems from Filedialog is already open by user?

Tags: excel, vba, filedialog

I need to build in a check to see if a workbook that is selected by the user through msofiledialogopen is already open on the users computer. How do you reference this workbook instead of using a fixed name like Workbooks("Example.xlsx")?

edit: The file is located on Sharepoint which may explain why I can't extract the name from the file path so easily.

The code I have so far is shown below:

```
Dim ItemSelected As String, ItemSelectedName As String
Dim wkb as Workbook

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen) 
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select Workbook"
    .ButtonName = ""
    
    ItemSelected = .SelectedItems(1)
    ItemSelectedName = Right$(ItemSelected, Len(ItemSelected) - InStrRev(ItemSelected, "\"))

End With

If Workbooks(ItemSelectedName) Is Nothing Then

Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(ItemSelected)

Else
    MSGBox "File already open"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I go about "checking" if a file is open in one of my workbooks.

Note that I do pretty much the same as you except I first check if the file exists at all through my two helper functions, and then attempt to open it in order to see if it's already open, instead of checking against the file name.

```
Option Explicit

Sub open_file()
    Dim wbMasterfile As Workbook, wbThisBook As Workbook
    Dim sFullFilePath As String, filnavn As String
    Dim masterfileAlreadOpen As Boolean
    
    sFullFilePath = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Innstillinger").Range("H2"))
    
    filnavn = Right(sFullFilePath, Len(sFullFilePath) - Application.WorksheetFunction.Max( _
                                                        InStrRev(sFullFilePath, "\", -1, vbBinaryCompare), _
                                                        InStrRev(sFullFilePath, "/", -1, vbBinaryCompare)))
    
    If sharepointFileExists(sFullFilePath) Or fileOnDisk(sFullFilePath) Then
            
        ' Open the file if it's not already open
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wbMasterfile = Application.Workbooks(filnavn)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If wbMasterfile Is Nothing Then
            Set wbMasterfile = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFullFilePath, ReadOnly:=True)
            masterfileAlreadOpen = False
        Else
            masterfileAlreadOpen = True
        End If
            
        ' What you want to do...
        
        If Not wbMasterfile Is Nothing And Not masterfileAlreadOpen Then
            wbMasterfile.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox Prompt:="Check that the filename and -path (in the sheet ""Innstillinger"") are correct.", _
                            Title:="Wrong path or name.", Buttons:=vbExclamation
    End If
    
End Sub ' open_file

Function sharepointFileExists(ByVal strUrl As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim oHttp As Object
    
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    oHttp.Open "HEAD", strUrl, False
    oHttp.Send
    'Debug.Print oHttp.Status
    sharepointFileExists = CBool(oHttp.Status = 200)
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    'Debug.Print Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    'Debug.Print "Feil: - " & oHttp.Status
    sharepointFileExists = False
End Function ' sharepointFileExists

Function fileOnDisk(ByVal strPath As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        fileOnDisk = .FileExists(strPath)
    End With
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    ' Debug.Print Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    fileOnDisk = False
End Function ' fileOnDisk
```

Comment: Thanks @eirikdaude! This part of your code actually worked perfectly to reference the name of the file which sits on sharepoint:

```filnavn = Right(sFullFilePath, Len(sFullFilePath) - Application.WorksheetFunction.Max( _
                                                        InStrRev(sFullFilePath, "\", -1, vbBinaryCompare), _
                                                        InStrRev(sFullFilePath, "/", -1, vbBinaryCompare)))```

Comment: I am lately trying to 'nail' error handling but it seems like a 'never ending story'. Why don't your `On Error` statements need a `Resume` statement (tested it, maybe not enough)? Or do they? Can you think of a scenario where the `fileOnDisk` procedure may raise an error?

Comment: if the fileondisk procedure raises an error (which there are several cases of) the procedure goes to the errorohandler and the function returns false. I had a question regarding why this function raised an error on this site some time ago, I'll see if I can find it for you @VBasic2008

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64965378/unexpecter-error-from-udf-which-checks-if-a-file-can-be-found @VBasic2008

Comment: Thanks for the link. The accepted answer though just confirms that error handling **may** not be necessary in the `fileOnDisk` procedure, which makes me wonder what the *several cases of* exactly are? Or at least one of them.

Comment: Tbh. I can't really recall. I was thinking of the error with `Dir` described in that Q&A though now that I changed the method that doesn't happen anymore. I would think if an empty string or maybe a lineshift was sent that might create an error, but I can't say for sure, sorry. @VBasic2008

Answer (score 0):

Try this **(not tested)**

```vb
Sub trySelectingItem2()
    Dim ItemSelected As String, ItemSelectedName As String
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select Workbook"
        .ButtonName = ""
        
        ItemSelected = .SelectedItems(1)
        'ItemSelectedName = Right$(ItemSelected, Len(ItemSelected) - InStrRev(ItemSelected, "\"))
        ItemSelectedName = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFilename(ItemSelectedName)
    End With
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wkb = Workbooks(ItemSelectedName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If wkb Is Nothing Then
        Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(ItemSelected)
    ElseIf LCase(wkb.FullName) = LCase(ItemSelected) Then
        MsgBox "File already open"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox "Another file with matching name is open"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Super Symmetry, i tried it and this part doesn't seem to work as intended - note i've tried it with GetFileName(ItemSelected) as i assume that's what you were going for. Would be nice if this worked though as it's quite succinct. 

```ItemSelectedName = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFilename(ItemSelectedName)```

Comment: Glad you found a working solution. Just note the case where there's a workbook open with a matching name but not the same selected file.