# Select each cell in range VBA to activate hyperlinks

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column in excel which contains a mix of hyperlinks, empty cells and non hyperlinks.

Manually I can press F2 and enter. This selects the highlighted cell, activates if a hyperlink is present and then moves onto the next one ready to repeat.

I wish to create a macro in VBA that achieves this however so far I can only get the cells to select but it does not active the hyperlink if present.

I appreciate it is possible to format the cells in excel as hyperlinks but this again only seems to create the illusion they have been activated (blue and underlined) i.e. they aren't clickable.

Attempt so far:

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim c As Excel.Range
     
    For Each c In Selection
    
    c.Select
    Debug.Print c.Value
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = c.Value

    Next c
```

Desired (iterate through each selected range of cells)

[image]

Comment: The issue is how to determine if the cell's value is a hyperlink candidate. If they all start with `www` then it's as easy as `If Left(CStr(c.Value), 3) = "www" Then c.Hyperlinks.Add c, CStr(c.Value)`. Maybe you could add more Criteria using If statements and make it work for you.

Comment: This is kind of what I expected but sadly they are still not clickable. I have to click them again to get this.  Not sure if this is something VBA can do.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the `https://`: `...c, "https://" & CStr(c.Value)`

Comment: Please add some data samples, does this text have preceding blank spaces?

Comment: no preceding spaces. Just centered

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I added an URL validation from another SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428611/vba-check-if-file-from-website-exists/25428811#25428811).

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim c As Excel.Range
Dim url As String
    For Each c In Selection
    
    c.Select
    Debug.Print c.Value
    url = trim(CStr(c.Text))
    
    If Left(url, 4) <> "http" Then
        
        url = "http://" & url
    End If
    
    If URLExists(url) Then
         
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:=url, TextToDisplay:=c.Text
    End If
 Next c

 
End Sub


Function URLExists(url As String) As Boolean
    Dim Request As Object
    Dim ff As Integer
    Dim rc As Variant

    On Error GoTo EndNow
    Set Request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    With Request
      .Open "GET", url, False
      .Send
      rc = .StatusText
    End With
    Set Request = Nothing
    If rc = "OK" Then URLExists = True

    Exit Function
EndNow:
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the response but unfortunately, this doesn't appear to change anything. It iterates over each value but nothing is activated as desired.

Comment: The output should be that black text, becomes a clickable hyperlink. The same way www.google.co.uk is recognised as a hyperlink and becomes active when you click on and then off the cell

Comment: this funciton creates an hiperlink only on existing URL, do you need another behavior?

Comment: Hm odd, for me it doesnt change anything. just prints the result of each cell

Comment: I call it `Macro1()`, are you executing Macro2 (your own macro)?

Comment: This solution requires an internet connection. It would run faster using `HEAD` instead of `GET`. Also, you need to use `c` as the parameter for the `Anchor` argument.

Comment: No I replaced the entire macro with yours

Comment: Just `c`, a range object, as stated in [Hyperlinks.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlinks.add).

Comment: @Nick check the last edit

Comment: @Horaciux This seems good. Seems to hand a little when changing between a hyperlink and non hyperlink but you've proved it can work